# Eager Loading with a relation dont exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl

im working in a app the uses ACL, and im loading my permissions on Auth Service Provider.

My php is:

```
$permissions = Permission::with('roles')->get();
```

Im getting a 500 error, and this is because in my permissions i still dont have roles associated with the permissions, I tried to check if there is a better way in using eager loading without still having roles? Is there a method that case it doesnt exists still gives me the permissions records and the roles empty or something?

Comment: What is the error thrown, could you paste the error response returned or the stack trace? Also, include your relationship definition and your controller method.

Comment: NO, if no relation whole object `role` will be null

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it should give you an empty collection of `roles`.

Assuming it's a many-to-many relationship between `Permission` and `Role` models, you need the following method in your `Permission` class:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```